# Obfuscate R.id class with or without proguard

Tags: android, ant, obfuscation, proguard, android-resources

I know in Proguard you are recommended to keep the fields names of the R inner classes like ID. Because ProGuard doesn't handle the layout xml files. You will end up with broken links

But is there away to obfuscate classes like R$id by some other means, even if it involves doing it before passing it to ProGuard, via Ant.

I am asking this because if you have a button with an id **btnSaveArticle**, for a hacker it becomes too easy to grasp what the code around is doing by looking at the name.

Could it be possible to copy all the source code, including the resource files to another folder and use ant to run regex to change the names of the R.ids as well as changing where they appear in the layout xml files, and then somehow running generate to re-create the R classes?

Or you could create translation class eg TR then map it to the fields in the R.class

eg.

```
TR.btnSaveArticle = R.id.DHTXM;
```

Where  DHTXM is some meaning less word that can be used in the layout XML. But in the code you always refer to TR.btnSaveArticle, which will be obfuscated by proguard.

Are there ways to achieve this or am I wasting my time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible through Ant, as it allows you to set a different gen and res folder.

So what you do is copy from the originals to those folders and then you edit the files using regex to update to the new names.

You will need a translation class (eg D) like this to map it to the fields in the R.class, so in your code you can work with non obfuscated names.

```
public final class D{
  public static final class id{
    D.btnSaveArticle = R.id.btnSaveArticle //DHTXM;
```

Then you also need to create a different src folder and copy from the original folder. There you run a task to edit the D class so  it becomes

```
   D.btnSaveArticle = R.id.DHTXM;
```

I had to create a java program which is run through ant to swap the names to obfuscated names.

If you do something similar for strings, and styles your XML in the apk would end up looking like this:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/GnvCMa"
        android:text="@string/OVuCbd"
        style="@style/ZOVkuu.MGTRgZ" />
```

It is a little time consuming to setup, but once implemented it can be used for other projects.

Answer (score 3):

Just use below ,add it to you Proguard config file

```
-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
public static <fields>;}
```

Answer (score 2):

> I am asking this because if you have a button with an id btnSaveArticle, for a hacker it becomes too easy to grasp what the code around is doing by looking at the name.

Using Hierarchy View, it would take them less than 30 seconds to determine the actual ID of the "Save Article" button, no matter what you name it. And I can envision even faster solutions with a bit of custom tooling.

> am I wasting my time?

IMHO, yes.

Comment: If you have a quite a few controls, it would take time to go figure all of them. Seeing a source file with all obfuscated names would make a casual hacker reluctant to hack. I do understand what you are saying, I still haven't been able to get to over the fact that a hacker can get the whole source code for Android Apps.

Comment: @pt123: "If you have a quite a few controls, it would take time to go figure all of them" -- by your own admission, they do not need to "figure all of them", only the important ones like "Save Article" that are of relevance to whatever they're trying to do to your app. "Seeing a source file with all obfuscated names would make a casual hacker reluctant to hack" -- only stupid ones.

Comment: @pt123: "I still haven't been able to get to over the fact that a hacker can get the whole source code for Android Apps" -- they can get to "the whole source code" of most client-side apps for most operating systems. Admittedly, bytecode-based languages like Java tend to be easier to decompile than native instructions. If you are concerned about the security of client-side apps, only write server-side apps (though, watch out for that pesky JavaScript in the browser!).

Comment: I don't care about someone looking to make a small change in the app, but worried about one able to make considerable change (eg.10%) and to upload it on Google Play. With native code this is harder to achieve. I have moved some parts to use JNI, wish Google provided more native libraries. My background was writing ASP.net pages, the JavaScript I wrote never contained anything important.

Answer (score 0):

With the default configuration for Android, ProGuard removes R classes entirely, unless your code performs introspection on them. In the latter case, ProGuard also preserves the fields with their original names, in order not to break the introspection.

That being said, the resource names can also be retrieved from the resource XML files, which ProGuard leaves untouched.

Comment: but why do the $R.id fields appear in the seeds.txt list, I am not using introspection, so what would happen to a call findViewByID(R.id.btnSave), does proguard replace it with the integer e.g. findViewByID(134234323)